# Prevent file access via web

Tags: linux

My mobile app will be serving images from my Ubuntu VPS.

Basically I have the images organized in a folder `\DATA`

What happens is, whenever an image is needed from the mobile application, a request comes to my back end, where it fetches the link of the image and sends it back to the user so that the link would open the image on the phone. For example, http://myexamplesite.com/Data/Image001.jpg

The images that I have are in sequential order. (Image001, Image002, Image003, etc).

What I want to achieve is, if someone finds the link http://myexamplesite.com/Data, and tries to access it via the browser, to deny him access. My goal is to make the images accessible only when it comes via a request from the mobile.

I am using
Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu 16.04)
Server built:   2016-07-14 T12:32:26
MySQL:          V5.7

Is such a thing possible on Linux?

Comment: You need to tell us more details! Which web server you are using?

Comment: @Khaled I updated my question and inserted the details below.

Answer (score 3):

You could make your mobile app set a unique 'user-agent' and then block all requests from other browsers. This will work as long as people do not find out what user-agent your app is using. (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html)

```
Require expr %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} == 'myMobileApp'
```

You can also serve the images through a simple PHP/Perl/Python/etc. script that requires you to include a 'key' in order to get the image.

Example: https://your.ubuntu.vps/images.php?id=image3&key=myMobileApp

It is also work mentioning that you should add a 'robots.txt' file that tells the search engines not to index the site. (http://www.robotstxt.org/) and disable browsing of the directory either by creating a blank 'index.html' or in a .htaccess/:

```
Options -Indexes
```

Comment: I guess should be stated that these are configuration changes in Apache, but this is what i would have suggested.